# Comparing OSGi vs maven?

Tags: java, maven, osgi

OSGi allows to add/change dependencies aka bundle, when Maven allows to add/change dependencies aka jars.

Then what the difference? It's like hitting the one goal by different ways

Comment: It feels you're asking what is the difference between a vegetable and a bicycle? Both terms are totally non related. Maven can be related to Ant or any such build making tools but OSGi is a way of creating services which other programs can use thus providing modularity.

Comment: @Raj, what sense to rewrite accepted's answer content?

Comment: Yes, you're right. This question would've been clear to you if you did some research on google. Clearly, this question itself makes no sense here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven is more of a build system you use to create OSGi bundles. The maven creators call it (I might be wrong on this) life cycle management tool. It helps you build, test, integrate and release (also deploy) your software. This includes dependency management on the library or component base.

OSGi on the other hand is more of a runtime thing where a bundle can add services or consume others. (I'm obviously no OSGi expert)

So you can use maven to create OSGi bundles but both technologies do not live in the same context. I think you cannot compare them. They serve a very different purpose.

Comment: However, they do intersect on dependencies declaration. That's the purpose of tycho project, I believe. In order to remove redundancies between the two (MANIFEST.MF and POM.xml dependencies).